# Android google maps v2 isproviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0,this) returns false always

Tags: android, google-maps

```
boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

The first one returns true when I have the GPS on, but the second one returns false even though im connected to my wifi. On the location settings i have enabled both gps and wifi for location determinations.

Comment: permission to access coarse location ?

Comment: In your device settings have you enabled network-based location? The WiFi can be on without the device being configured to use WiFi and cell towers for location.

Comment: coarse and fine locations are enabled. internet too

Comment: a network service(network location i think) was disabled in my applications, causing this problem. After enabling it again and restarting the application, it seems that, finally, the droid asked me for permission to store network data on the phone regarding my location

Answer (score 0):

We need more information like api level.

Check this thread, this must solve your problem. And if you want to get location, just use the google_play_service locatioClient.

[Network Connection is closed but location provider is NetworkProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19566163/network-connection-is-closed-but-location-provider-is-networkprovider)

Answer (score 0):

After some thorough search on the phone's settings, my Network Location app was disabled for some unknown reason. Wifi was turned on, and both gps and network were chosen for location settings. So after turning it back on and a phone restart, I was finally asked to allow the droid to store my location on the phone